# jQuery .on-method not working on dynamically added items

Tags: jquery, ajax, dynamic

I have hundreds of

```
<button class="lb">
  <div class="l"></div>
  <div class="c">2</div>
  <div class="r"></div>
</button>
```

which a few are already in the DOM when the page is loaded and others are added dynamically through javascript.

When someone clicks on the button, the value inside the div class="c" inside of the button should be heightened by 1.

I thought I could do that like this

```
$(".lb").on("click", function(event) {
  $('.c', this).html(parseInt($('.c', this).html()) + 1);
  $(this).unbind('mouseout');
});
```

but that does only work on the elements that are loaded on pageload and not on the new per-JS-inserted ones.

I can't find what I'm missing and would appreciate any hint.

Thanks!
Raphael

Comment: View the [.on()jQuery API Documentation Page](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events), to the Direct and Delegated Events section. It shows you the two examples there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a few concepts of using `.on()` as a delegate:

```
$(' --CONTEXT-- ').on('click', ' -- YOUR ELEMENT -- ', function () {

});

// like-wise to "unbind" using the new methodology
// you would use .off()
$(' --CONTEXT-- ').off('click', '-- YOUR ELEMENT --');
```

So to put it in example form:

```
$(document).on('click', '.lb', function () { });
```

But of course this makes the context (or where it will be "bubbling up towards") **document** which is too high up. Try using a large parent surrounding wherever this item may appear, it will speed up performance.

```
$('#someParent').on('click', '.lb', function () { });
```

Comment: You want to try not to use `$(document)`, that is what `.live()` and such used to use as the context. Try to use a lower-level parent, so that there isn't as much bubbling up during the delegation event.

Comment: yes I did, thanks! I have a surrounding div and I use it's class as a context. I think that's how I should do it?

Comment: Yes, just make sure that `.lb` won't be appearing anywhere else (at least anywhere else where you want this click functionality). And you'll be all set.

Answer (score 3):

Use event delegation to parent of `.lb` or `document`. As @Zolton Toth pointed you should be useing `off` instead of deprecated `unbind`.

```
$(document).on("click", ".lb", function(event) {
  $('.c', this).html(parseInt($('.c', this).html()) + 1);
  $(this).off('mouseout');
});
```

Comment: + change the deprecated `.unbind()` to `.off()`

Comment: oh... that line was left over from when I used another method above... thx!

Comment: @RaphaelJeger so you _don't_ want to unbind anything?